# The pattern value under Rules in Yii, why stars with "/" and ends with "/u"?

Tags: php, regex, yii

I am analyzing some regex concepts basics, we all know '^' symbol used in beginning of expression starts with some value and '$' used in the end for expression ends with certain value and if they are used together '^exp$' it can be matched only by exp. But in Yii while declaring rules like

**For allowing only numbers we give**

```
public function rules()
{                        array('value', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[0-9-]+$/u','message' => "Incorrect symbols (A-z) ."), }
```

I just want to know why we are using that **trailing "/u" and "/" leading** in our rules. 
Thanks friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading `/` and trailing `/u` doesn't have anything to do with Yii.

They come from the syntax used to create regular expressions in PHP.

You create regular expressions in PHP by enclosing them inside two sets of delimiters, usually the delimiters used are a pair of `/` symbols, but you can use any pair of [non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) as delimiters.

```
/^[0-9]+$/u
^--------^
These two are the delimiters used to create the regular expression
```

Now as for the `u`, anything that comes after the closing delimiter is called a [regular expression modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and it is used to configure various options for the regular expression engine.

```
/^[0-9]+$/u
         ^---------
         Anything from here on is a regular expression modifier
```

`u` lets the regular expression engine treat the pattern as a Unicode string of characters, it is useful when your patterns contain Unicode characters that you are using to match Unicode text.

Take a look at the [PHP reference documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) for regular expressions to understand the basics of regular expressions in PHP.